# Minimal size taken by a small object in AppCache

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

Get-CacheStatistics command shows that any small object (even 1 Integer) takes at least 1024 bytes in cache memory. Is it correct and is there any way to adjust AppCache to handle memory more efficient for small objects?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is an error in your understandings.

It's true taht objects are stored in the cache in a serialized form but there are other internal data structures that require memory in the cache : key, duration, named cache, regions, tags, notifications, ... take a look on [capacity guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334304%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

There is no way to manage internal cache data structure.

Comment: Well, I aware of serialization and other overheads. But it strongly looks like there is something like a "page size". You may put Int32[] or String into AppCache and Get-CacheStatistics will show:

Size              : 1024
ItemCount         : 1

But as soon as your Int array get bigger than 847 or your string grow up to 848 there will be another cache page allocated for the cached object:

Size              : 2048
ItemCount         : 1

That's what I meant.